# Extracting major version from version in c#

Tags: c#, regex, split

I've a string like

```
myString = "some (numbers) \string \stringwithversion 12.3.45";
```

example string

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Product\Product Edition 12.3.45
```

**I need to get 12 as output**

it thought of splitting string with spaces and split result again with spaces and get first one;

```
myString.Split(' ').Last().Split('.').First();
```

whereas i've seen something with regex matching and getting from groups [i don't understand it].

whats the best to get the major version from string like this?

Comment: Can you give us a example of the one of the strings that you will be parsing?

Answer (score 2):

The regex:

```
[^0-9]*([^\.]*)\..*
```

The explanation:

1. `[^0-9]*`: Find 0 or more chars that aren't numbers. Discard all f them.
2. `[^\.]*`: Find 0 or more chars that aren't a period.
3. `([^\.]*)`: Capture those chars (i.e. you can assign them to a variable, `$1`).

(NOTE: I assume that the only numbers in the string are from the version!)

The code:

```
string strRegex = @"[^0-9]*([^\.]*)\..*";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.Multiline);
string strTargetString = @"some (numbers) \string \stringwithversion 12.3.45" + "\n";
string strReplace = @"$1";

return myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, strReplace);
```

You can test it [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/).